# Passport Local strategy not called

Tags: javascript, passport.js, mean-stack, passport-local

I use angularJS+passport to perform user authentication and hence, i set up these below.
HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="logincontroller">
<form>
Email:<input type="text" ng-model="user.email"/>
Password:<input type="password" ng-model="user.password"/>
<div ng-click=loginUser()>Submit</div>
</form>
</div>
```

In client side javascript:

```
  app.controller('logincontroller',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.loginUser=function(){
    $http.post('/loginUser',JSON.stringify($scope.user));
   }
   })
```

ON app.js

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser=require('cookie-parser');
var passport=require('passport');
var LocalStrategy=require('passport-local').Strategy();
var session=require('express-session');
app.use(express.session({secret:"flibbertygibbit"}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {usernameField: 'user.email',
    passwordField: 'user.password',
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
    function(username,password,done){
      console.log("am here"+username+" "+password);

}
))


app.post('/loginUser',passport.authenticate('local'));
```

The problem i face is the Local strategy isnot being called at all and all I get Typerror: Local strategy requires a verify callback. I ain't sure where i went wrong, being novice at it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is caused by this:

```
var LocalStrategy=require('passport-local').Strategy();
                                                    ^^
```

You're calling the `Strategy` class without any arguments, so this results in the error. You want to store a reference to the class itself, like this:

```
var LocalStrategy=require('passport-local').Strategy;
```

Also, because you're setting `passReqToCallback : true`, the verification callback will take *four* arguments, not three. It should look like this:

```
function(req, username, password, done) { ... }
```

Comment: You were absolutely right. Sorry for the silly mistake . I rectified it and now i don't get Type Error but I get 400 - Bad request . Could you please let me know why ?

Comment: @Gayathri I'm not sure if the way you're posting the data is correct (perhaps not call `JSON.stringify()` on it, but I'm not too familiar with Angular so not sure).

Comment: I didn't add name attribute to html and that's the reason why the values didnot pass to strategy.